# How to make good context classes/return references in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, reference, shared-ptr

I'm coming from a C# background, and am trying to create a well structured C++ application (in this case a game using SFML, but the question is not specific to anything game-related).

When it comes to passing parameters and returning I'm used to values by value, references by value, values by reference and references by reference. I think this roughly maps to the following, but correct me if I'm wrong.

```
(int    number) or (int    number) // value     by value
(someClass*  c) or (someClass&  c) // reference by value
(int*   number) or (int&   number) // value     by reference
(someClass** c) or (someClass*& c) // reference by reference
```

To achieve proper cleanups, I rather use smart pointers, and I'm wondering how I should implement a context class.

A context class will contain and own several components of the game, such as the asset manager (which loads and/or caches resources), scene references, etc. This context class will contain read-only references to the components, but the components are not necessarily read-only.

In C# the logical choice there would be to have getters that retrieve a reference to the specific components. Ie. `AssetManager& getAssetManager() const;`

Currently to store it I'm using a private field `unique_ptr<AssetManager>` that is initialized in the constructor. So cleanup should happen in the destructor. Returning happens with `*fieldName`.

There no need for it to be a `shared_ptr` since the lifetime of the `AssetManager` should be controlled by the `GameContext`.

**Question 1:** Is this the proper way to return such a value from a context class or should I use a different construct (move constructor comes to mind, but my knowledge of C++ is very limited and I have no idea if I'm making any sense right now.)?

**Question 2:** How should I return the `sf::Font` class from the `AssetManager`. Again `sf::Font& getFont(std::string name);` seems like an option, but what's the way to go?

Comment: `const` is important.

Comment: `AssetManager& getAssetManager() const;` you can use such signature but you'll have to omit the `const` to return a non const reference to your internal member.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is returning a reference to a mutable object bad?

Comment: I would not recommend  it. Why not simply remove the const?

Comment: That was a short statement sent from my phone before. I would not recommend it, because that way (making the member mutable) you're hiding the semantics. Usually the `const` member functon indicates the corresponding class instances's data won't be changed, and you can't change anything via the returned reference. If you have a member function that returns a non const reference to a data member ths functon shouldn't be declared as a `const` member.

Answer (score 1):

Remark re lines 2 and 3 in your table: C++ does not require you to make a formal distinction between someClass* and int*.

Generally accepted OO lore says that returning anything but an immutable reference of anything that's a component of a class (that is not a container) is a no-no, and even this should be watched with a careful eye, as it creates a binding between client and class. The "clean" way is to have a set of methods in the hosting class and delegate the calls to the member object. This, of course, also applies to the members of members (`sf::Font` of `AssetManager`).

Otherwise, returning a reference is preferred to returning a pointer, which may or may not burden the receiver with the responsibility of taking care of returning allocated memory.

This is the typical way of returning a reference to a member without permitting modifications:

```
private:
 std::string name;
public:
 const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
```